# Joining 3 lists to one list with many items

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and I am stuck. I've been playing with this a lot. I am trying to get my 3 lists to join and when I do python says that the new list only contains 1 item. How do I get them to merge completely?

here is the code I have now :

(where avg[] is some array containing lots of data)

```
q=avg[0:40]

p=avg[53:70]

u=avg[95:145]

pu=p+u

NF=[numpy.append(q,pu)]

>>>len(NF)

>>1
```

but the actual length of all the items is 107.
Please help

Comment: just do `NF = p + q +u` and you should be fine

Comment: @RNar if `p` and `q` are np arrays then "+" is not a concatenation (OP says "lists", but later clearly uses numpy so this is far from being clear)

Comment: OP, please clarify: is avg a list or a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

If `avg` is list, then `q`, `p` and `u` are slices of a list and therefore will be lists too. In that case, you could concatenate the lists using addition:

```
q+p+u
```

If you want a NumPy array, you could use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
In [48]: avg = np.arange(20)

In [49]: q = avg[0:4]

In [50]: p = avg[5:7]

In [51]: u = avg[9:14]

In [52]: np.concatenate([q,p,u])
Out[52]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

I made the arrays smaller so the result is easier to check.
Other alternatives include [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack) and [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
In [53]: np.hstack([q,p,u])
Out[53]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

In [54]: np.r_[q,p,u]
Out[54]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

In the above examples, `q`, `p`, and `u` may be NumPy arrays or Python lists. In each case a NumPy array is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You put your array in another array. try this:
`NF=numpy.append(q,pu)`

Answer (score -1):

```
q=avg[0:40]

p=avg[53:70]

u=avg[95:145]

pu=p+u

NF=[numpy.append(q,pu)]  #problem right here just do NF = numpy.append(q,pu)

>>>len(NF)

>>1
```

Comment: It is better you explain the code, code-only answers are considered as poor quality answer.

Answer (score -1):

Okay this is going to be horrifically slow, maybe numpy has its own way of doing it, but using python way and provided that you have one-dimensional arrays, try this:

```
from itertools import chain

items = chain.from_iterable([avg[0:40], avg[53:70], avg[95:145]])
```

The statements about will return a generator, that can be converted into a list that reports you its length.

```
item_list = [x for x in items]
len(item_list)
```